# How to specify memory allocation for Pandas Dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, memory-management, out-of-memory

I am trying to merge two big pandas dataframes but it raises a memory error on my 4GB RAM laptop so I tried on in computer lab on 16 GB RAM but it's  still raising the same error (**on the same line code crashes** ).

I am not able to resolve why pandas raising the same error and not using the 16 GB RAM space. Please help me to resolve it .

```
feature_AtomPairs2DFingerprintCount=pd.read_csv("/home/adarsh/big_data_features/AtomPairs2DFingerprintCount.csv")
feature_AtomPairs2DFingerprinter=pd.read_csv("/home/adarsh/big_data_features/AtomPairs2DFingerprinter.csv")

merged_data_2=pd.merge(feature_AtomPairs2DFingerprinter,feature_AtomPairs2DFingerprintCount,how='left')



MERGED_DATA=pd.read_csv('/home/adarsh/comp_des.csv')


total_merged=pd.merge(MERGED_DATA,merged_data_2,how='left')
```

Comment: Can you show us your code too? Besides adding memory, its possible there is room for optimization.

Comment: use [dask](https://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/) if dataframe is huge.

Comment: Chances are, your code is doing something you don't intend it to, perhaps an accidental Cartesian join. Try doing the merge on a smaller subset and see what happens.

Comment: @jsalonen ,@ken Wei  , I have added the code.

Comment: How big are the files and which line exactly is throwing up the memory error (presumably one of the merges?) For big data files then Pandas alone might not be fit for your needs, possibly consider looking into something like Spark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resource.getrlimit call will tell you the hard and soft limits for various system resources.  For memory

```
    soft, hard = resource.getrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_AS)
```

The softlimit is the value which, when reached, the operating system will typically restrict the process or notify it with a signal.  The hard limit represents an upper bound on the values for the softlimit.  The softlimit can be modified with an appropriate call to resource.setrlimit().  The hard limit is typically controlled by a system-wide parameter set the the system administrator.  It cannot be raised by user level processes, although it can be lowered.  This is reported to work on Linux but not MacOS or Windows where it returns -1 for both values.

I suspect that you are running up against the OS's max for process size.